# Is there a way to access data from a Kendo grid using dataSource.data() WITH grouping?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My Kendo version is 2013 and upgrading is not an option right now. I need to export the data to excel and I am successfully doing that by exporting the data with

```
$("#someGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
```

followed by a bunch of controller code. The problem is this data loses it's grouping state when attempting to retrieve it using dataSource.data(). Is there a simple way within the Kendo Framework to maintain the data's grouping information/sorting?

Comment: What @SiliconSoul proposed is valid, you should take a look on it. But bear in mind that the `view()` method gives you another data pattern, different from `data()`. [Check this out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIpA5.png)

Answer (score 1):

The dataSource [view](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/view) method returns the data with applied state. If you need the grouped data without paging then you can use the [Query](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/query) class to apply the current group state to the original data.